# writing a loop for upscaling precipitation for USA

Tags: r, netcdf

I am writing a code to calculate the mean amount of precipitation for different regions of conterminous USA. My total data has 300 times 120 (lon*lat) grids in Netcdf format. I want to write a loop in R to take the average of each 10 by 10 number of grids and assign that value (average) to all of the grids inside the region and repeat this for the next region. At the end instead of a 120 by 300 grids I will have 12 by 30 grids. So this is kind a upscaling method I want to apply to my data. I can use a for-loop for each region separately but It makes my code very huge and I don’t want to do that. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks.
P.S: Here is the function I have written for one region (10by10) lat*lon.

```
upscaling <- function(file, variable, start.time=1, count.time=1)
{
  library(ncdf)   # load ncdf library to manipulate ncdf data
  ncdata <- open.ncdf(file);      # open ncdf file
  lon  <- get.var.ncdf(ncdata, "lon");
  lat  <- get.var.ncdf(ncdata, "lat");
  time <- get.var.ncdf(ncdata, "time");
  start.lon <- 1
  end.lon   <- length(lon)
  start.lat <- 1
  end.lat   <- length(lat)
  count.lon <- end.lon - start.lon + 1;   # count number of longitude
  count.lat <- end.lat - start.lat + 1;   # count number of latitude
  dat <- get.var.ncdf(ncdata, variable, start=c(start.lon, start.lat, 1),               
                      count=c(count.lon, count.lat, 1))
  temp.data<- array(0,dim=c(10,10))
  for (i in 1:10)
  {
    for (j in 1:10)
    {
      temp.data <- mean(dat[i,j,])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you just loop through all the regions using this function? Wouldn't you just have this code and a small loop which passes each file to your function?

Comment: NOTE: you can not use MEAN to average over a regular lat/lon grid, you need to account for the grid box sizes or your answer will be incorrect. Better to use CDO for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to make a messy loop to spatially aggregate your data. Just use the aggregate function in the raster package:

```
library(raster)
a=matrix(data=c(1:100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
a=raster(a)
ra  <-  aggregate(a,  fact=5,  fun=mean) #fact=5 will aggregate using a 5x5 window
ra=as.matrix(ra)
ra
```

Now for your netcdf data, use raster's rasterFromXYZ to create the raster that can then be aggregated with the above method. Bonus includes the option to define your projection as an argument in the function so you end up with a georeferenced object at the end. This is important because if you aggregate your data without it you will then have to figure out by hand how to georeference the resulting matrix.

EDIT: If you want a resulting raster with the same dimensions as the original one, disaggregate the data right after aggregating it. While this seems redundant, these raster methods are very fast.

```
library(raster)
a=matrix(data=c(1:100),nrow=10,ncol=10)
a=raster(a)
ra  <-  aggregate(a,  fact=5,  fun=mean) #fact=5 will aggregate using a 5x5 window
ra  <-  disaggregate(ra, fact=5)
ra=as.matrix(ra)
ra
```

Comment: Thanks Lucas. That's a very good idea but there is just one issue with that. At the end "ra" gives me a 12 by 36 matrix. what I need is a 120 by 360 matrix that the values at each set of 10*10 arrays inside the matrix (rows*columns) are equal.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, if you want to keep the original resolution, use the focal function: ra  <-  focal(a,  w=5,  fun=mean)

Comment: No your answer was perfect and very helpful. I think I didn't convey what I want from the code very well. thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I just checked the values of the focal fx I suggested and I think I was wrong- check the edit I have to my answer which now I believe does exactly what you requested.

Comment: NOTE: you can not use MEAN to average over a regular lat/lon grid, you need to account for the grid box sizes or your answer will be incorrect.  The size of the error will be small for this particular task (resolution is fine, and is only a 10x10 average) but the answer will be off.

Answer (score 0):

If you grid definitions follow standard netcdf conventions, then you might be able to remap using the CDO remapping functions.  For first order conservative remapping you can try

```
cdo remapcon,grid_specification_here in.nc out.nc
```

Note that the answer given above is approximate, and not quite correct as the grid cell size is not the same as a function of latitude.  The size of the error is likely small for this particular task as the cell sizes are fine, but nevertheless the answer will be slightly off.